# Is remote debugging .NET Core Linux Docker container with Visual Studio Code from Mac/Windows possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

Is it possible to debug a .NET Core application running in a Linux Docker container from another (remote) Linux/Mac/Windows developer machine running Visual Studio Code?